# Let $f,g : \Bbb R \to (\Bbb R, \tau_1)$, where $\tau_1$ is the lower limit topology. Show that the topology induced is the discrete topology.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Let $f,g : \Bbb R \to (\Bbb R, \tau_1), f(x)=x, g(x)=-x$, where $\tau_1$ denotes the lower limit topology. Show that the topology induced by $f$ and $g$ is the discrete topology.

My attempt. Let $[a,b) \subset \Bbb R$. Now since $[a,b) \in \tau_1$ it's open in $\Bbb R$. Now $f^{-1}([a,b)) = \{x \in \Bbb R : x \in [a,b) \}$. Also $g^{-1}([a,b)) = \{x \in \Bbb R : -x \in [a, b)\} = \{x \in \Bbb R : x \in (-b, -a]\}$. But depending on $a,b$ both of the preimages would be just $\Bbb R$ since $a,b$ can be any reals? This would mean that the topology induced is just $\Bbb R$ and since $\emptyset$ is a subset of any set the induced topology would be $\{\emptyset, \Bbb R\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But depending on $a,b$ both of the preimages would be just $\Bbb R$ since $a,b$ can be any reals?

$a,b$ can be any reals, but preimages are not $\mathbb{R}$. How do you conclude that say $f^{-1}([a,b))=\mathbb{R}$? That's not the case, in fact $f^{-1}([a,b))=[a,b)$, while $g^{-1}([a,b))=(-b,-a]$. You even said that yourself (in a bit longer way)!

> This would mean that the topology induced is just $\Bbb R$ and since $\emptyset$ is a subset of any set the induced topology would be $\{\emptyset, \Bbb R\}$?

No. The statement refers to [the initial topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology). It is topology generated by all preimages $f^{-1}(U)$ and $g^{-1}(V)$ over all open subsets $U,V\in\tau_1$.

So given an open subset $[a,b)$ we have that $f^{-1}([a,b))=[a,b)$ while $g^{-1}([a,b))=(-b,-a]$. We can apply this to concrete intervals, to obtain that say $[a,a+1)=f^{-1}([a,a+1))$ is open and $(a-1,a]=g^{-1}([-a,-a+1))$ is open for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$, in our initial topology. But their intersection is a singleton $\{a\}$ which has to be open as well. Since $a$ was chosen arbitrary it follows that any point is open and thus the topology is discrete.